# How to select only direct subClassOf element in a GraphDB custom ruleset?

Tags: rdf, rules, inference, graphdb, rdfs

In a GraphDB custom ruleset, I need to access only the explicitly declared superclass of an element, but I can't find any predicate (like `sesame:directSubClassOf`), nor use the implicit/explicit context (`onto:explicit` / `onto:implicit`). Any workaround I've tried so far has failed.

To illustrate the issue, say I have the following triples:

```
:x :rdf:type :a.
:y :rdf:type :b.
:z :rdf:type :c.
:a rdfs:subClassOf :b.
:b rdfs:subClassOf :c.
```

Because of transitivity, after inference (I ignored reflexivity here):

```
:x :rdf:type :a.
:x :rdf:type :b.
:x :rdf:type :c.
:y :rdf:type :b.
:y :rdf:type :c.
:z :rdf:type :c.
:a rdfs:subClassOf :b.
:b rdfs:subClassOf :c.
:a rdfs:subClassOf :c.
```

With this custom rule:

```
Id: hasDirectLinkTo
    c1 <rdfs:subClassOf> c2
    i1 <rdf:type> c1
    i2 <rdf:type> c2
    -------------------------------
    i1 <:hasdirectlinkto> i2
```

I obtain all the instances of `c1` and its superclasses linked to all the instances of `c2` and its superclasses, by the predicate `:hasdirectlinkto`, while in this case, I don't want the superclasses. Here:

```
1. :x :hasdirectlinkto :y
2. :x :hasdirectlinkto :z
3. :y :hasdirectlinkto :z
```

Where I don't want to get line 2 `:x :hasdirectlinkto :z`.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks!